# Sort JsonNode inside ArrayNode in some sequence using java jackson API

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have to sort the entities based on their attributes. There is priority given to attributes based on that I need to sort the objects.

Given input looks like:

```
[
   {"Clever":false , "Singer":true , "Actor":true ,  "Dancer":false},
   {"Clever":false , "Singer":false , "Actor":true ,  "Dancer":false},
   {"Clever":true ,  "Singer":false , "Actor":false,  "Dancer":true}
]
```

And this is what expected:

```
[
   {"Clever":true ,  "Singer":false , "Actor":false,  "Dancer":true},
   {"Clever":false , "Singer":true ,  "Actor":true ,  "Dancer":false},
   {"Clever":false , "Singer":false , "Actor":true ,  "Dancer":false},
]
```

I want to do something like:

```
priority = ["Clever" ,"Singer" , "Actor"] 
      
list.sort(priority);
```